# When to use the bare infinitive?

Tags: verb-usage

In this [post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71151/how-does-one-translate-that-something-comes-about) it was said that the use of "kommen" with "heraussprudeln" has to be constructed in this way:

> kam wieder **hervorgesprudelt**

But Hammer's German Grammar gives this sentence as correct:

> Kommst du heute **schwimmen**?

So why is the Hammer's sentence not:

> Kommst du heute **geschwommen**?

or the post's sentence:

> kam wider **heraussprudeln**

Comment: Abhängig von Semantik und Kontext kann man auch mitgeschwommen kommen: "Kämna (dt. Tour-de-France-Fahrer) kam gestern nur im Peloton (Fahrerfeld) mitgeschwommen." (Perspektive eines Zuschauers, der im Ziel auf seine Ankunft wartete.) Der Fachjargon und die Theorie, um das Warum allgemeingültig zu formulieren (Passiv?) fehlt mir; daher keine Antwort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the participle and using the infinitive have different meanings.

The infinitive can be used with verbs such as "(mit)kommen", "gehen", "fahren" to mean "come/go to do something", that is, that you do a movement in order to go to a place where you can do something.

> Kommst du heute mit *schwimmen*?

> Are you coming to swim with me?

This construction can be used with any kind of activity and is very common.

The participle specifies the means of coming. It is therefore only possible with intransitive verbs that imply a motion, for example with "heraussprudeln" or "schwimmen". It is also exclusively used with "kommen", not with other verbs of motion.

> Marlene kommt *geschwommen*.

> Marlene comes swimming

Often a form already implying a motion towards the speaker is used, with "her" or "an".

> Marlene kommt *angeschwommen*

Note that there is no verb "anschwimmen" (at least not with that meaning), the "an" comes from the construction.

The focus is on "coming", but it is also specifying the means. That is why
is sounds strange in pleas or questions. For example in

> *Kommst du geschwommen?

"geschwommen" is superfluous. If "schwimmen" was the focus, one would say

> Schwimmst du hierher?

The focus on coming is why this construction is used a lot in plays and stories. Characters enter the stage, and while the focus is on them entering, the means is also conveyed.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I can help you with my answer.

> Kommst du heute mit schwimmen?

In this sentence, the german verb used is not "kommen" but "mitkommen".
I would translate "mitkommen" to "to accompany someone" or "to join someone".

Example:

> "Kommst du heute Abends mit ins Kino?"

Will you accompany us to the cinema this evening? Will you join us...?

Examples for usage of "kommen":

> "Kommst du aus England?" / "Bist du aus England?"

Are you from England?

> "Der Regen kommt vom Himmel"

The rain comes from the sky.

"Geschwommen" ist einfach das Partizip von "schwimmen".

> "Ich bin heute morgen (vor 3 Stunden) im See geschwommen"

Comment: I will edit the question so that the verb is specifically kommen.

Comment: When you compare this answer with the one from Dodezv, I think you'll find that this only tangentially answeres the OP.